# Vaadin How to place the content to Tabsheet within the full space available?

Tags: java, vaadin

I am a newcomer in Vaadin. Does any one know how to put the buttons (Save) down to the right corner of the tabsheet bottom. While the main content to be displayed within the full size of the useful space of the tabsheet. 
My code:

```
TabSheet tabs = new TabSheet();
        tabs.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABSHEET_FRAMED);
VerticalLayout content = createContent();
        tabs.addTab(content, "File Content");

private VerticalLayout createConten() {
VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
Group group = new Group("Group:");
      groups.setMultiSelect(true);
      groups.addItems(presenter.getGroups())
Button save = new Button("Save");
       save.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
verticalLayout.addComponent(groups);
verticalLayout.addComponent(saveAclBtn);
return verticalLayout;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Did you get the chance to check out the [docs' layout formatting section](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-settings.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
// ...
verticalLayout.setSizeFull();
verticalLayout.setExpandRatio(groups, 1f);
verticalLayout.setComponentAlignment(saveAclBtn, Alignment.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
return verticalLayout;
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. But tt seems doesn't work for me properly. The button is aligned to the bottom_right while the content (groups) took a small part of vertical layout. I had to use css to set height and width in pixels for groups. Still I think tt such solution is more than unwanted 'couse  assumed values were interpreted by Chrome, Mozilla etc., in a different manner.

Comment: Consider debugging your layout with the `?debug` parameter. That opens up the Vaadin debug window. Also use the Developer Tools of Chrome and look for the `slot` css classes inside the vertical layout. That gives a lot of information where your glitches are in the layout. And avoid overriding settings in CSS.